# All files being pulled from wp-content returning 404 error

Tags: 404-error, content

I am on a fresh install of Wordpress on Ubuntu / LAMP, and noticed that none of my site's images are showing. I tried to install a theme (Sydney) and none of the images were showing up. I was able to fix this by manually installing the theme to the wp-content directory. You can see in the image below that all of the files being requested from wp-content are returning 404 errors. I tried uploading images, but they are returning a 404 error as well. I tried finding them in the wp-content/uploads folder but that folder didn't exist. As far as I can tell, the images just disappeared after I uploaded them. I am sure I configured something wrong, but I don't know what. How do I correctly configure the uploads folder so that my images show up? If anyone knows the solution to the problem of the themes not installing correctly, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, did you check your LAMP configuration ? Try to access a static HTML page with images, then a simple php script. 
If it's ok, then try to disable any plugin, mu-plugin and use a native wordpress them (such as twentyseventenn). You can also turn debug on in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

to display php error in the UI. Perhaps it could help to find the issue.